# Machine Learning imputable "common-sense" datasets

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I need a dataset that can be used to build **imputation** models upon and that is also a **"common-sense"** data such as countries econometrics, **Forbes2000** etc. That is, I am not interested either in customer survey datasets or sensor dataset.
 I have already tried to compile **countries econometrics dataset** which include fields such as gdp, gdp per capita, population, internet penetration rate, poverty etc. to impute missing poverty rates for example.

Unfortunately, all of the different techniques I have tried failed utterly and produced no meaningful models. I have also tried **Forbes2000** datasets to predict market value of a company based on other available information on the aforementioned dataset. Although somewhat better than the econometrics dataset, this also failed with no reproducible models with a high predictive power.

Now I am stuck, since I can not find any other dataset that has "common-sense" data (for a lack of a better word) and also machine-learnable. If you could advise any hints, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing an ML model, the cool way to find relevant data is to launch a data search in [upgini](https://github.com/upgini/) library.

It searches for relevant features for the ML model through data about 700+ mln phone numbers, 400+ mln emails, 239 countries, and up to 41 years of history.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I was searching for. Gotta check it out in detail.

Comment: Hey @aftermidnight, your answer sounds a lot like a marketing message. Please [clearly state your affiliation](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) with upgini in your answer, otherwise your posts will probably get deleted as spam.